# Hololens Placing Objects With Spatial Understanding

Tags: hololens

I have been running SpatialUnderstandingExample scene from holo-toolkit. Couldnt figure out how to place my objects into the scene. I want to replace those small boxes that comes default with my own objects. How can I do that?
Thanks

edit: found the draw box but how do i push my object there?

edit2: finally pushed an object at the position but still code is very complicated its messing up with the size and shape of my object. Will try to make it clean and neat.

Comment: Do me a favor, and post your edit 2 as a new question.  I can give you a bunch of examples of how I handled that, I don't want to violate stack overflow rules and answer two different questions in the same question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've looked at that example so hopefully I remember its method name's correctly. It contains a "DrawBox" method that is called after a successful call to get a location from spatial understanding.  The call that creates the box looks something like this:

```
DrawBox(toPlace, Color.red);
```

Replace this call with the following (assuming "toPlace" contains the results from the spatial understanding call and "model" contains the model you are trying to place there):

```
var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(toPlace.Normal, Vector3.up);

// Stay center in the square but move down to the ground
var position = toPlace.Postion - new Vector3(0, RequestedSize.y * .5f, 0);

// instantiate the hologram from a model
GameObject newObject = Instantiate(model, position, rotation) as GameObject;

if (newObject != null)
{
     // Set the parent of the new object the GameObject it was placed on
     newObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
}
```