# HoloToolkit Spatial Understanding and Object Placement

Tags: hololens

I have been trying to place objects into the room with the data taken from spatialunderstandingExample scene. But the code is really not understandable to me. Did anybody achieved this using spatialtoolkitexample? Any help?

https://github.com/Microsoft/HoloToolkit-Unity/tree/master/Assets/HoloToolkit-Examples/SpatialUnderstanding/SpatialUnderstanding-FeatureOverview/Scripts

all the scripts are here, in UI script  Query_OnFloor_AwayFromMe() gets called then I kinda lose track of the code until draw_box from linedrawer script gets called. In draw_box  I tried the following to bring my hologram there but nothing shows up.

```
  mydummy.SetActive(true);
  mydummy.transform.position = new Vector3(center.x,center.y,center.z);
```

Comment: Based on your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40728179/hololens-placing-objects-with-spatial-understanding/40729295#40729295), you have successfully replaced the default box with a hologram of your own but you are struggling to get it to place correctly and scale to the right size, before I post an answer, is that correct?

Comment: I thought I did but it was a gameobject i forgot to turn off.  So I am back there again :(

Comment: If you can post your current code somewhere I'll have a look at it.

Comment: updated , thanks Cameron

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with trying to explain what is going on in this sample.  Starting from the call in UI.cs to Query_OnFloor_AwayFromMe()...

1. this makes a call into LevelSolver.cs.  Inside this method it is creating a new PlacementQuery object and calling PlaceObjectAsync.
2. PlaceObjectAsync creates a new thread with a call to System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run where the actual work of calling spatial understanding is getting done.  This work must be done in a seperate thread because it takes a very long time so it needs to be executed across multiple frames or your app will lock up during execution.
3. On the new thread PlaceObject is called, this makes the actual call to Spatial Understanding (SpatialUnderstandingDllObjectPlacement.Solver_PlaceObject) which is a call to the C++ HoloToolkit, this is the call that take s a long time.  When this completes the result is added to placementResults which is basically a work queue.
4. In LevelSolver.cs there is an Update method, this gets called every time that unity draws a new frame.  There is a call in here to Draw_PlacementResults.
5. Draw_PlacementResults loops through every result in the placementResults work queue and calls Draw_AnimatedBox in LineDrawer.cs
6. That is how you get to the call to Draw_Box we were discussing in the previous question.

So the other question is how do I modify this example to put your own model in place.  I would suggest making your modifications in LevelSolver.cs.  Try changing Update() to something like this:

```
private void Update()
{
    // Can't do any of this till we're done with the scanning phase
    if (SpatialUnderstanding.Instance.ScanState != SpatialUnderstanding.ScanStates.Done)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Make sure the solver has been initialized
    if (!IsSolverInitialized &&
        SpatialUnderstanding.Instance.AllowSpatialUnderstanding)
    {
        InitializeSolver();
    }

    // Constraint queries
    if (SpatialUnderstanding.Instance.ScanState == SpatialUnderstanding.ScanStates.Done)
    {
        Update_Queries();
    }

    // Handle async query results
    ProcessPlacementResults();

    MyProcessPlacementResults();
}
```

This will cause it to stop drawing boxes and instead call "MyProcessPlacementResults" to handle doing something with the results.  I would add a method something like this to LevelSolver.cs.  (In the code I'm borrowing from I was creating a tree)

```
private void MyProcessPlacementResults()
{
    if (placementResults.Count > 0)
    {
        var toPlace = placementResults.Dequeue();

        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(toPlace.Result.Forward, Vector3.up);
        CreateTree(toPlace.Result.Position, rotation);

    }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using to actually instantiate the tree in the correct spot:

```
private GameObject ThisIsYourCustomModelInMineItWasATree;
private Vector3 TheSizeIPassedToSpatialUnderstanding = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

public void CreateHologram(Vector3 positionCenter, Quaternion rotation)
{
    ThisIsYourCustomModelInMineItWasATree = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);

    GameObject newObject = Instantiate(ThisIsYourCustomModelInMineItWasATree, positionCenter, rotation) as GameObject;

    if (newObject != null)
    {
        // Set the parent of the new object the GameObject it was placed on
        newObject.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;

        newObject.transform.localScale = StretchToFit(ThisIsYourCustomModelInMineItWasATree, TheSizeIPassedToSpatialUnderstanding);
        newObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
    }
}
```

And just for completeness here is the code I used to scale it to the desired size:

```
private Vector3 StretchToFit(GameObject obj, Vector3 desiredSize)
{
    var curBounds = GetBoundsForAllChildren(obj).size;

    return new Vector3(desiredSize.x / curBounds.x / 2, desiredSize.y, desiredSize.z / curBounds.z / 2);
}

private Bounds GetBoundsForAllChildren(GameObject findMyBounds)
{
    Bounds result = new Bounds(Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero);

    foreach (var renderer in findMyBounds.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
    {
        if (result.extents == Vector3.zero)
        {
            result = renderer.bounds;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Encapsulate(renderer.bounds);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I've also changed the private variable placementResults from a List to a Queue.  I did this because the List was used to draw a box in every frame.  We want a queue because we are going to instantiate a new object once and let the unity engine manage it.  Find the line:

```
private List<PlacementResult> placementResults = new List<PlacementResult>();
```

and change it to:

```
private Queue<PlacementResult> placementResults = new Queue<PlacementResult>();
```

After making that change you will need to fix a couple of places.  Remove the method Draw_PlacementResults, it is no longer used anyway.  Change the two places that call placementResults.Add to placementResults.Enqueue.

Comment: Is this your actual code? In MyProcessPlacementResults()  i cant dequeue placement results it doesnt let me. I tried to get them one by one still didnt work...

Comment: Yes it is my code, I ripped it out of a much larger project, which is not based on the example you are working out of.  You are right, my placementResults is an actual queue, I'll edit my answer to try and fix that.

Comment: nope that didnt work either.. I guess I will position them manually for now, thanks for all your help.
Do you mind sharing your project with me?

Comment: Sorry I can't it contains many things I don't have the rights to distribute (mostly purchased off the unity asset store)

Comment: I was just pushing my luck :) Thank you Cameron

Comment: This was bugging me that we didn't get it working... So I did a get of the repo and made all the changes and built it myself and then fixed up the couple things that weren't right.  In addition I defined the variables ThisIsYourCustomModelInMineItWasATree, TheSizeIPassedToSpatialUnderstanding so it actually works as written without changes.

Comment: Of course I defined model and size but what other changes did you do? Like fixing code errors due to changing list to queue? 
Can you share the new project ?

Comment: All the updates are in the edited answer, pretty much every chunk of code changed a bit including one I missed completely

Comment: Thanks Cameron , sorry I couldnt reply sooner I was away for a while. Gonna get working on this asap!